# How can I make xcode build and run armv7 version for iPhone6

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having hard time getting `armv7` build to run on iPhone6. Xcode stubbornly insists on using `arm64` and when I try to change things it fails in all possible ways and prevents me from running `armv7` build on iPhone6.

Things that I've tried: Set to "No" for `Build Active Architecture Only`. I end up with a bogus `Invalid bitcode signature` message that means nothing to me without telling what piece/lib exactly had that invalid signature.

Ideally I would like to make a fat build with all supported archs (`armv7`, `armv7s`, `arm64`) and then to be able to run each one of them on iPhone6 to compare/profile code to see differences (I'm ok to re-link for each arch, as long as I don't need to rebuild entire world each time when I want to cahnge arch). How can this be done on Xcode and how can I set/override active arch?

Comment: Can you tell please did you solve this? we have a similiar problem

Comment: @Petr see accepted answer. Worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making **Build Active Architecture Only - NO** to work, you must also set **Enable Bitcode** to **NO**.

[image]

Comment: I'm changing all my libs now to not use bitcode, but after that how do I make final project to use some arch, how do I make `armv7` active?

Comment: If you have set the above and in the final project add armv7 in **Valid Architectures** (also found in project build settings), it would work.